# ASP.NET web forms and external authentication service

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

I have an ASP.NET webforms (not MVC!) application. I used built-in internal user authentication mechanism, which means using `web.config` file:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Logon.aspx" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" timeout="180" slidingExpiration="true">
    </forms>
</authentication>
<authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

`Logon.aspx` page asks for the user's login and password, then uses `FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage()` method for login and `FormsAuthentication.SignOut();` for logout.

Now I need to migrate to external authentication server. This server uses software like OAUTH, but not quite (it is self-developed). So, I cannot understand a scheme, how to implement a third-party auth server to web forms.

Should I place a third-party auth server redirect url to my `web.config`? Or should I make two redirects, first to `Logon.aspx`, then to external auth link from it? How to make a logout procedure? unfortunately, I have experience only in built-in web forms authentication, and even cannot imagine how to work with external service!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the `Grant Type` there are different flows you can use: https://oauth.net/2/grant-types/

> The most common OAuth grant types are listed below.
>
> Authorization Code
>   Client Credentials
>   Device Code
>   Refresh Token

For web applications the Authorization code is most probably the way to go:https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/04/10/oauth-authorization-code-grant-type

> The application opens a browser to send the user to the OAuth server
>   The user sees the authorization prompt and approves the app’s request
>   The user is redirected back to the application with an authorization code in the query string
>   The application exchanges the authorization code for an access token

Basically,  you will not be using your form at all. You'll be redirecting to and from the oauth server.